# Comparison query operator ObjectId <-> Date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to execute comparison queries `$gt`, `$lt`, etc. of a `Date` against an `ObjectId` and vice versa? Does the mongodb driver cast this automatically? Does this mongodb server cast this automatically?

Comment: can you give an example in the question edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

It is possible under the JavaScript based methods to get a date from the ObjectId value in which you can use for comparisons. It also should be possible to construct an ObjectId given a specific date value as well, but not seeing the utility of that though. But all are valid and essentialy by date:

```
ObjectId("53473d87cb495e216c982929") > ObjectId("53473e57cb495e216c98292a")

ObjectId("53473d87cb495e216c982929").getTimestamp() >
ObjectId("53473e57cb495e216c98292a").getTimestamp()

ObjectId("53473d87cb495e216c982929").getTimestamp() >
ISODate("2014-04-11T00:55:35Z")
```

So forms such as this will work, even if really not that great a statement:

```
db.collection.find({ 
    "$where": function() {
         return this._id.getTimestamp() > new Date("2014-01-01");
    }
}
```

As for the "creation" of `_id`'s they are either done in the "driver" or explicitly by the user, or if still omitted the server will generate one.

Comment: So I can't compare a `Date` object to an `ObjectId` object or vice versa directly in the query object?

Comment: @paulkon Added one possible usage example to clear that up. JavaScript based queries are certainly not good news for performance so you really should look at other methods to avoid this. But it can be done.

Comment: I have to use `$where` for that?

Comment: @paulkon $where invokes a JavaScript interpreter for evaluating over each condition, much the same goes for mapReduce. The method to obtain the timestamp from the _id is only available server side under JavaScript execution. Sadly methods like aggregate as yet lack the necessary math and casting operators required to otherwise obtain the timestamp from the id. Otherwise that would be a much better method.